# Bootstrap alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im making a Bootstrap3 based website. I am Using AJAX to LOAD THE PHP PAGES INTO apDiv2 But For Some reason the Content of the pages keep loading and starting under the top navigational section. Even when resized the content from the pages are overlapped by the Navigation bar at the top... and It hides things.How Do I get it to anchor to that set position to appear right under the Top Nav Bar So that Its no overlapping .... this is te code I am using

SEE IT LIVE @ www.ForeverThaEmpire.com

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
<center><img src="content/images/fdelogo.png" width="210" height="60" /></center> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">      </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> 
<center>    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form></center>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3"> </div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<img src="content/images/twitter.png" width="30" height="30" />
<img src="content/images/facebook.png" width="30" height="30" />
<a class="menu_nav" href="pages/shoppingcart.php"><img src="content/images/cart.png" width="40" height="40" /></a><br>
<div class="simpleCart_grandTotal"></div> 
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div id="well"><div id="apDiv2"></div></div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom"></nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your navbar is fixed on top, so it goes over the body tag which contains your loading div.

Try adding this to your CSS

```
body
{
    padding-top:70px!important;
}
```

Comment: I am using BootStrap CSS style Sheet? If I put this in a custon CSS and have it load before the bootstrap CSS will It overwrite the BootStrap CSS? becuase I tried this with changing the Font Color but it didnt work?

Comment: It will override as long as you make use you use the !important tag after the value of the CSS field